# some data table not seeds in Laravel 7 with Laratrust

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7, laratrust

I am using Laravel 7 and Laratrust 6 for the authentication part. but when I run `php artisan db:seed` command some of following tables `users,role_user,permission_user` are not seeds with data. how could I fix this problem?
My DatabaseSeedr.php file is as following

```
<?php
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder
{
    public function run()
    {
        $this->call(LaratrustSeeder::class); 
        }
}
```

Comment: You need to run those seeder file as like `$this->call(UserSeeder::class); ` `$this->call(UserRoleSeeder::class); `

Comment: may I need separate seeder files for User and UserRoles etc..

Comment: Yes. But may be you already have that all, on `.../database/seeds/` check that directory

Comment: I have only DatabaseSeeder and LaratrustSeede in the directory

Answer (score 1):

Go to `LaratrustSeeder.php` file. Change  `'create_users' => false`, to `true`.
Refresh your migrations and seed again.